# MS-DOS check folder size

Tags: windows, ms-dos

My computer has crashed, so I only have access to the CMD. I am backing up my hard drive, and I just want to make sure that I copied everything from my Documents folder.

How do I check the entire say, /User/Desktop size using MS-DOS? When I use dir, it will only show the file sizes, and the number of folders inside Desktop!! What do I do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you really talking about MS-DOS, or do you mean the Windows command prompt, e.g., while booted in Safe Mode?

Comment: Executing `C:\> dir /A /S` would help! Overall size will be displayed at the end of the command.

Answer (score 2):

This command will list the size of a given directory:

```
dir "c:\users\yourNameHere" | find "(s)"
```

This command will copy directories (and contents) and the /v switch will verify that the destination files are identical to the source files:

```
xcopy "source\dir\path" "destination\dir\path" /v
```

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) is documenation about xcopy command and switches.

Answer (score 1):

Download [du.exe from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651). Slap that on a USB drive and run this from your cmd prompt. This will allow you get a complete listing of all subfolders with sizes. For example, you could run: `du /accepteula desktop` to get the size of the desktop folder. (You'll need the `/accepteula` param to suppress the EULA dialog that normally comes up when you run this.)

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /a/s folderName
```

And if you prefer results recorded in a file, of course:

```
dir /a/s folderName > myresults.log
```